# TripleDES in C#, not the same value with tool

Tags: c#, tripledes

In a page with a tool online encrypt a Text with Triple DES:

```
Key: 09F15B103BC56A6FA705E71F0850EE6D
IV: 0000000000000000
Text: 9876543210123456FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
Encrypted value: 3AA4CCDEE3F753A3CE62B72252386873
```

In C#, i have a code, but i can't get the same value.

```
public static string Encrypt(string toEncrypt, string _key) {
 TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
 byte[] iv = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
 var CharHex = GetHexFromAscii(toEncrypt);
 var input = ParseHex(CharHex);
 tdes.IV = iv;
 tdes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
 tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
 ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
 byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(input, 0,
          input.Length);
 tdes.Clear();
 var resTemp = Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);}}
```

Does anyone know why?

The page with the tool is 
http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/descalc/index

Comment: The tool doesn't returns base64 but raw hex values.

Comment: How can I get the same value?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa

Comment: Thank you very much my friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of class  `System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001.SoapHexBinary` :

```
TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] iv = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
var input = SoapHexBinary.Parse("9876543210123456FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF").Value;
tdes.IV = iv;
tdes.Key = SoapHexBinary.Parse("09F15B103BC56A6FA705E71F0850EE6D").Value;
tdes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(input, 0, input.Length);
tdes.Clear();
var resTemp = BitConverter.ToString(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
```

It returns same output. `3A-A4-CC-DE-E3-F7-53-A3-CE-62-B7-22-52-38-68-73`

Comment: Thank you very much my friend